# TypeORM - Add extra column when custom column on OneToMany

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I want to create a custom column for my `@ManyToOne` entity. When I have used this code
[image: Code which I used]

And the result is:
[image: And the result is]

There has been added `countryId` column. What I must to do fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you have to use decorator `@RelationId` like this:

```js
export class Province {
  //...
  @Column()
  @RelationId((province: Province) => province.country)
  public countryId: number;
}
```

Please use next time block code with code definition.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it. But the result is the same. column ```countryId``` still appear.

Comment: Ahhh, so get ride of the `name` from the @JoinColumn

Comment: Ya, that's right, can you give me a solution?

Comment: I just did it in the comment above